# Can a shochet answer his own shechita shailos?

Tags: halacha, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Is a shochet allowed to slaughter for himself, or does he need to buy from another butcher?

If he slaughters an animal, and questions arise as to the validity of the shechita, can the shochet answer the questions for himself?  Is there any concern as to his personal involvement in the question?

Answer (score 6):

The [last Taz in Y.D. siman 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.18.15), based on the Rash, writes that even though a Talmid Chochom is generally believed to paskin for himself, he is not believed when there is a *chezkas issur*, a previous status of prohibition.  The animal was prohibited to eat while it was alive, and therefore the shochet is not relied upon to paskin for himself in this situation.

However, with regards to slaughtering for himself if no questions arise, there is a principle that רוב מצויין אצל שחיטה מומחין, most of those doing shechita are experts, and he is therefore allowed to shecht his own dinner.

The Chayei Adam [klal aleph se'if 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33594&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=) accepts this Taz.

Comment: May a Yid anser his own Mi Yodeya question?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I actually [had an agenda for asking](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20040384#20040384)

Comment: But as long as you mentioned it, an important meta post on the topic http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/306/if-i-know-the-answer-to-a-question/307#307

Comment: Since rabbis often consult other rabbis I imagine shokhets consult other shokhets. Of course there are those feel that doing so somehow affects their reputation.

Comment: @JJLL I'm under the impression that when a shochet has a question, he'll ask a rabbi. As far as I'm aware, this has always been the case, and it's still this way today. (*My father, for example, sends his questions to rabbis. That time he asked about the goat was probably the weirdest question my rav ever got* :P)

Comment: Hey @shokhet. As I understood it the IP was asking asking does a shokhets have to consult another person if a question arises or can he answer it himself since he technically is an expert by virtue of being a shokhet.

Comment: @JJLL I thought that it was a question about *psak halacha*, rather than just "another opinion." `@YeZ, was I right about that?

Comment: @Shokhet Yessir. But I'm not sure if that is what JJLL meant also.

Comment: Hey, YeZ, the question is yours so only you know what you intended. Perhaps I overread as I often do. I read your question as two, maybe three. First, can a shochet shekhet for himself or would that be a "conflict of interest" as he might reject an animal that is perfectly kosher or conversely accept an animal that was is not kosher. Or is it like a physician who ethically is not suppose to treat himself or his/her immediate family and thus a shokhet should not use the meat. Secondly, just by the vurtue of being a shokhet, can on judge/answer questions that others ask him when slaughtering an

Comment: animal. That is to say, if questions arise, why wouldn't a shokhet (who would answer the same exact questions if someone else asked him) be able to draw his own conclusions? Personal issues are an issue which may lead to being more stringent or less stringent. If everyone had to consult with someone else in their field of expertise, nothing would ever get done

Comment: I apologize for my response above. I am on my lunch break at work and realize that my response may be unclear. I'lol work on it after שבת.

Comment: @JJLL The second question was whether he can answer his own questions that arise through his own slaughter.  If he shecths an animal, and there is a question about the validity of his own shechita, and he happens to know hilchos shechita and treifos, can he answer the question for himself.

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific p'sak (is that the correct term) @YeZ but why couldn't he? If he is certified shokhet, he is qualified to answer most questions that arise. Afterall, he himself might be consulted on the same issue by someone else. Given the nature, however, of the issue at hand, should he answer for himself? Probably not as it is very difficult to not be biased on a personal level. Why would it be problematic for the shokhet to consult someone else even if he did not have to? Some rabbis do as such when they are not certain of something even though their s'micha permits....

Comment: ......them to decide. Is there an anecdotal record kept concerning a shokhet's track record deciding the kosher status of a slaughtered animal versus an independent opinion? On the other hand, history has shown that kosher standards have varied widely well into the 20th century. Perhaps this would be reason enough for a person with invested interest in shekhtering for self to consult someone if a question arises.

Comment: @JJLL I don't understand your comments.  "Why couldn't he?" followed by the reasoning of why he shouldn't.  I don't know if you think I am asking something different than what I explained I am asking.  The question is very simple - can he be מורה הוראה for himself.  I don't understand why you keep bringing up consulting other shochtim or rabbis.  I'm not asking for good advice - I'm asking if he is allowed to consult himself, for exactly the reason you mentioned why he might not be able to (and indeed the cited Taz says he shouldn't). If I am missing something please fill me in.

Comment: YeZ you are YeZ. It's not you, it's me. My mind is always in overdrive and it goes in all directions. I am quite surpirsed that your question did not receive more responses. Someone else can respond more clearly than I.

Comment: Just to clarify, what questions would arise concerning whether a valid shekhita was achieved? Are you referring to questions such as Did I use the proper knife? Was the knife properly sharpened?

Comment: @JJLL Shokhet could probably answer your question better than me, but I assume it could be questions of treifos, a safek in rov simanim, or anything that would have to be closely examined to decide on.

Comment: @yez Okay YeZ, I thought you were referring to some unstated question when you wrote: "If he slaughters an animal, and QUESTIONS arise as to the validity of the shechita, can the shochet answer the questions for himself?"

Comment: @YeZ Perhaps not for a little while; I've been pretty busy recently, and it's not going to stop for a while....everything SE is going to have to take a break for a little while :(